# Difference between $E(X\mid Y)$ the random variable and $E(X\mid Y=y)$ the number

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

I asked this question in class and I didn't understand my professor's answer. We have just recently began making the distinction between random variables (e.g. $Y$ and $X$) and a specific, fixed value (e.g. $y$ and $x$).

This issue first came up today when we discussed the Law of Iterated Expectations.

We stated that $E[X|Y]$ is a random variable that takes the value $E[X|Y=y]$ when $Y$ takes the value $y$. Because of this, we can consider $E[X|Y]$ as a function of $Y$ since $E[X|Y=y]$ is a function of $y$.

I'm just curious why this distinction is necessary. Why can't it just be implied that $E[X|Y]$ is a function of $y$ since $X$ is conditioned on the random variable $Y$ which takes on any value $y$ in the domain of $Y$?

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, note that in "Why can't it just be implied that E[X|Y] is a function of y", one does not even know what y should be. Absurd, eh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the right answer, but listen to what you just said:

"$E[X|Y]$ is a random variable that takes the value $E[X | Y = y]$ when $Y$ takes the value $y$".

This is the exact same idea as saying $f(x)$ is the function that takes the value $f(c)$ when $x$ takes the value $c$.  Just as in this sentence we are regarding $x$ as our *variable*, the thing we freely change to get different outputs, so too in the above sentence we are regarding $Y$ as our variable, then thing we are freely changing.

It just so happens that $Y$ is a random variable at the same time, i.e., its values depend on future outcomes which are uncertain at the present time.

Comment: The analogy to f(x) really did it for me. Thank you!

Comment: "This is the exact same idea as saying f(x) is the function that takes the value f(c) when x takes the value c." The *exact* analogy to the probabilistic statement would rather be: "This is the exact same idea as saying fog is the function that takes the value f(c) when evaluated at x such that g(x)=c" (or, in the present context, the function that takes the value f(y) when evaluated at omega such that g(omega)=y).

Comment: @Did, I sort of get that; however, I question whether or not the random variable $Y$ can be considered analogous to $g(x)$ since $Y$ is not a function but rather a random variable. $g(x)$ has an input and output while $Y$ just takes on a value

Comment: @DavidSouth Random variables are functions. All of them.